# Java fill 2d array with 1d arrays

Tags: java, arrays, function, 2d

Whats the nicest way to fill up following array:

 From main:

```
String[][] data = new String[x][3]; 

for(int a = 0; a < x; a++){ 
    data[a] = someFunction();
}
```

Function I am using..:

```
 public String[] someFunction(){
     String[] out = new String[3];

     return out;
 }
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Or do I have to fill it with for-loop?

With this code im getting error "non-static method someFunction() cannot be refferenced from static content ---"(netbeans) on line `data[a] = someFunction();`

Comment: You could try this out, perhaps? Not sure how you want to produce the data for the array elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your someFunction() by adding "static".

You also should consider using an ArrayList for such tasks, those are dynamic and desinged for your purpose (I guess).

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int x = 3;

    String[][] data = new String[x][3]; 

    for(int a = 0; a < x; a++){ 
        data[a] = someFunction();
    }

}

public static String[] someFunction(){
     String[] out = new String[3];
     return out;
 }
```

Greetings Tim

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify how many rows your array contains.

```
String[][] data = new String[n][];

for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    data[i] = someFunction();
}
```

Note that `someFunction` can return arrays of varying lengths.

Of course, your `someFunction` returns an array of null references, so you still have to initialize the `String`s of that array in some loop.

I just noticed the error you got. Change your `someFunction` to be static.

Comment: I did specify. String[][] data = new String[x][3]; x*3 and someFunction gives String[] out = new String[3];

Comment: @Vedran My mistake. I thought you meant that x implies an arbitrary length.

Comment: Any idea what I could do?

Comment: @Vedran change your `someFunction` method to static.

Comment: oh. totally missed that. Thanks for your help!